# Finding the area and perimeter of a flower formed by many cardioids

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, polar-coordinates

I just made this simple Desmos model of a flower formed by rotating and translating multiple cardioids. Here is an example of what a flower with 6 petals looks like:

[A "cardioid flower" with 6 petals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIXFC.png)

Here is the Desmos model:

[Link to Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lhf1ffoq1b)

I am currently trying to figure out how to find expressions for:

1. The area of the flower formed
2. The perimeter of the flower formed

However, I have no experience in doing anything like this and I am struggling to figure out where to start/what I need to learn even after spending a few days looking around online. Based on what I currently know, I am under the impression that this has something to do with integrals, so I've been trying to teach myself basic calculus. Could I please have guidance? I would really appreciate it!

Edit: here is the equation for the "base" cardioid. Copies of this cardioid are translated and rotated around the origin to form the flower.
$$
\left(20\left(1-\sin\left(t\right)\ \right)\cos t,\ 20\left(1-\sin\left(t\right)\right)\sin t+10\right), 0\le t\le2\pi
$$

For a flower with 6 petals, the original cusp point of the cardioid at (0, 10) is rotated by 60 degrees, and so is the cardioid itself. For example, here is the equation for the directly adjacent cardioid:
$$
\left(20\left(1-\sin\left(t+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\right)\cos t+5\sqrt{3}\ ,\ 20\left(1-\sin\left(t+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\right)\sin t+10\right)
$$

Here is the result:

[image: Result]

This is repeated 6 times for a total of 6 petals.

Comment: Do you know the integral formulae for the area enclosed by a polar curve?

Comment: I have seen a related video on youtube, but I couldn't figure out how I could calculate the isolated area in the flower and leave out the rest of the cardioid.

Comment: If you share the formula you used for the cardiods, maybe we can help you identify the induced polar equation of the flower

Comment: Just added the equation to the post, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Nice. Welcome to the site

Comment: Thank you, and thank you for the advice haha

Comment: By integration find one sixth length and area around cusp  $ -\pi/6< \theta< \pi/6,$ then multiply by 6.